# Executing run function of threading.Thread object independent of main

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a class that is inheriting threading.Thread, and I have included the threading.Thread.**init**(self) in my init method, and have overridden the run method. However, when I launch the thread using myObject.start(), the main loop is not independent of this and rather waits. Note, I am not using join() anywhere.

The desired behavior is that after starting the thread with myObject.start(), the thread keeps on executing while the main function keeps on executing.In the below example, after running myObject.start(), I would want "MY OTHER CODE" to launch immediately, regardless of what my thread is doing.

myObject = Object(arg1, arg2)

myObject.start()

MY OTHER CODE

MY OTHER CODE

Thank you

**EDIT**
Part of Gmail class:

```
def gmailAPIEmailQueue(self, labelList):
    try: 
        searchResult = self.gmailAPIMessageLabelSearch(labelList)
        if searchResult is False: 
            logging.error("Failed to search for emails with labelList (" +str(labelList)+ ")")
            return False
        for targetID in searchResult: 
            targetEmailID = targetID['id'] 
            emailMessage = self.gmailAPIGetFullMessage(targetEmailID)
            if emailMessage is False:
                logging.error("Unable to get email associated with the emailID (" +str(targetID)+ ")")
                continue
            emailContent = self.gmailAPIExtractEmailContent(emailMessage)
            if emailContent is False:
                logging.error("Failed to get email content associated with emailID (" +str(targetID)+ ")")
                continue
            attachments = self.gmailAPIDownloadAttachments(targetEmailID)
            if attachments is False:
                logging.error("Failed to download email attachments associated with emailID (" +str(targetID)+ ")")
                continue
            theEmail = Email(attachments, emailMessage, emailContent)
            (self.emailQueue).append(theEmail)
        return True
    except:
        logging.error("An error was encountered in Gmail Email Queue")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        logging.exception(tb)
        return False

def run(self):
    while True: 
        self.gmailAPIEmailQueue(self.labelList)

def __init__(self, email, password, labelList=['INBOX', 'UNREAD'],port=993, server='imap.gmail.com'):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
    self.serverConnection = None
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.port = port
    self.server = server
    self.gmailAPIService = None
    self.emailQueue = list()
    self.labelList = labelList
    result = self.gmailAPIInitialize()
    if result is False:
        logging.error("Gmail API Failed to Initialize")
        sys.exit(-1)
```

In my program main:

```
myGmail = Gmail(emailAddress, emailPassword, searchLabel)
myGmail.start()

theEmailQueue = myGmail.gmailAPIGetQueue()
#OTHER CODE, Such as other threads.
#
#
#emailProcessor = EmailProcessing(var1,var2)
#emailProcess.start()
```

I want myGmail and emailProcessor to run simultaneously, but as of now, it waits on myGmail.start().

Comment: I think we'll need more information before we can help.  Perhaps if you could offer some sample code to at least how you are inheriting threading and then starting the thread.  That is, can you create a simple example to demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Thanks, I have added additional code.

Comment: Edit: It was just Visual Studio. Program behaves as intended